# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a user clicks on a team logo, I want a click to perform that will append a paragraph tag under the clicked element and then insert the team name into the paragraph tag.

This is my HTML file and JS file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>jQuery Lab!</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content">
        <h1>NFC EAST</h1>

        <div>
            <img src="http://www.nationalsportsbeat.com/images/logos/nfl/New_York_Giants_Helmet.jpg" alt="Place Kitten"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img src="http://www.nationalsportsbeat.com/images/logos/nfl/Washington_Redskins_Helmet.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img src="http://www.nationalsportsbeat.com/images/logos/nfl/Philadelphia_Eagles_Helmet.jpg" alt="Place Kitten"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img src="http://www.nationalsportsbeat.com/images/logos/nfl/Dallas_Cowboys_Helmet.jpg"/>
        </div>


    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My jquery file

```
$(function () {
console.log("javascript loaded");

var teams = ['New York Giants', 'Washington Redskins', 'Philadelphia Eagles', 'Dallas Cowboys'];

var $teamsArray = $('div');
$teamsArray.addClass('teams-container');

$teamsArray.each(function()
var $paragraph = $('<p>');
$(this).append('<p>').html(teamsArray{i});

});
```

However , in the console, I keep getting a

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var"

that refers to this line:

```
var $paragraph = $('<p>');
```

Anyone know the issue?

Comment: your missing an open curly brace `{`..   `$teamsArray.each(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

You have few of syntax errors. First of all, don't have the proper opening and closing brackets for the each loop.(`({   })`). Also for accessing the array item using index, use `[index]` instead of `{index}` . Also i believe you wanted to access the `teams` array to add the item to the `p` tag.

This should work.

```
$(function () {
   var teams = ['New York Giants', 'Washington Redskins',
                                                 'Philadelphia Eagles', 'Dallas Cowboys'];

  var $teamsArray = $('div');
  $teamsArray.addClass('teams-container');

  $teamsArray.each(function(a,b){     
     $(this).append('<p>').html(teams[a]);
  });
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/pecuxo/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample.